# Imitate coloring of an image using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have two images of a scene and one of them is gray-scale.
what I want to do is overlay the colored image over the gray-scale one and make the impression of coloring the gray-scale image.

So far I came close to the effect using this command:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i colored.jpg -loop 1 -i grayscale.jpg -lavfi "[1:v]crop=iw:ih/5:0:'if(gte(t*ih/10,ih-ih/5),ih-ih/5,t*ih/10)'[strip];[0:v][strip]overlay=y='if(gte(t*H/10,H-H/5),H-H/5,t*H/10)'[out]" -map '[out]' -t 10 -y coloring.mp4
```

But the result is neither complete nor smooth.
any help is appreciated.

NOTE one liner solutions are preferred and ffmpeg is the only tool that i can use.

Comment: Please include the complete console output from the command.